# How to create a decoder for an Either type with Circe?

Tags: scala, circe

If you are expecting to receive either a Json of a type `A` or type `B` (`Either[A, B]`), how could you write a decoder for it?

For example, let's say you are building a client for an external API that can answer with some expected Json structure:

```
{
  "fieldA": "value",
  "fieldB": "value2"
}
```

or if something fails, it will answer with an object with an `error` field:

```
{
  "error": "Your request was wrong"
}
```

And then you want to have an instance with either of those structures:

```scala
val response: String = // Response from the server 
val decodedValue =
  decode[Either[ErrorResponse, ExpectedResponse](response) // (...) <- What implicit to place here?
```

How can you write a decoder for either one response structure or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Circe issue 672](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/672#issuecomment-309840983), you can write a generic decoder for Either in the following way:

```scala
implicit def eitherDecoder[A, B](implicit a: Decoder[A], b: Decoder[B]): Decoder[Either[A, B]] = {
  val left:  Decoder[Either[A, B]]= a.map(Left.apply)
  val right: Decoder[Either[A, B]]= b.map(Right.apply)
  left or right
}
```

**Note:** For this approach, you still need to implicitly define a decoder for `A` and for `B`. In most cases, using `deriveDecoder` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

To slightly simplify the previous answer:

```scala
implicit def eitherDecoder[A, B](implicit a: Decoder[A], b: Decoder[B]): Decoder[Either[A, B]] =
  a.either(b)
```